# Appending lines to D3 bar chart - absolutely nothing happens

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an otherwise fine working grouped bar chart script to which I'm trying to add simple reference lines. The relevant code:

```
//Set up margins and dimensions according to http://bl.ocks.org/3019563
var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 30},
    width = 810 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

/* Set up the primary x scale */
var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1)
    .domain(data.map(function (d) {
        return options.xPrimaryScaleAccessor(d);
    }));

/* Set up the secondary x scale */
var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(xSecondaryScaleValues)
    .rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);

/* Set up the y scale as a linear (continous) scale with a total range of 0 - full height and a domain of 0-100 */
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, 100]);

/* Set up a color space of 20 colors */
var color = d3.scale.category20();

/* Set up the x axis using the primary x scale and align it to the bottom */
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

/* Set up the y axis using the y scale and align it to the left */
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

/* Create an SVG element and append it to the body, set its dimensions, append a <g> element to
 * it and apply a transform translating all coordinates according to the margins set up. */
var svg = d3.select(options.target).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Create a space for definitions
var defs = svg.append("defs");

setupDropShadowFilter(defs, 3, 3, 3); //Sets up a gaussian blur filter with id 'drop-shadow'

/* Append a <g> element to the chart and turn it into a representation of the x axis */
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

/* Append a <g> element to the chart and turn it into a representation of the y axis */
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(options.yLabel);

var dataArr = y.ticks(yAxis.ticks());

/* Draw the reference lines */  
svg.selectAll("line")
   .data(dataArr)
   .enter().append("line")
   .attr("x1", 0)
   .attr("x2", width)
   .attr("y1", y)
   .attr("y2", y)
   .style("stroke", "#ccc");

/* Set up the bar groups */
var group = svg.selectAll(".group")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(options.xPrimaryScaleAccessor(d)) + ",0)"; });

/* Draw the bars */
group.selectAll("rect")
    .data(options.valueAccessor)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.label); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr('rx', options.barCornerRadius)
    .attr('ry', options.barCornerRadius)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return getStripedPattern(defs, color(d.label)); //Sets up a pattern and returns its ID })//Todo: fill with pattern instead. see http://tributary.io/tributary/2929255
    .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)");

/* Draw a legend */
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(xSecondaryScaleValues)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + (xSecondaryScaleValues.length-i-.25) * (height/xSecondaryScaleValues.length) + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", width - 9)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
    .attr("y", 9)
    //.attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - 6) + ",-8)rotate(-90)" )
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

EDIT: I have also tried to append `rect` elements instead with hardcoded coordinates and dimensions, but those also didn't make it to the DOM.

EDIT 2: More or less full code now included.

Basically, nothing happens. No lines are appended and there are no errors in the console. The dataArr is a plain array of numbers and `y(number)` is confirmed to return good values in the output range.

I think (and debug suggests) that the chain dies at the `append()` stage, possibly because `.enter()` return something useless.

#### Console log after `.data()`:

[image: Console log after .data()]

#### Console log after `.enter()`:

[image: Console log after .enter()]

#### Console log after `.append()`:

[image: Console log after .append():]

I've been stuck on this for a good while now, so grateful for any ideas about what may go wrong. I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious...

Comment: Must be something in the rest of the code that you're not showing us. The basic pattern works fine for me -- http://jsfiddle.net/eHTFq/

Comment: Thanks for the proof of concept @LarsKotthoff. I guess you are right, but I don't know what other code to share. I basically have a working thing with the code before and after the line appending code working as intended. When I have time I will review my question and see if I can post more code.

Comment: Do you have `line`s in your SVG already?

Comment: No @LarsKotthoff, I use lines for no other purpose. I should use it for the striped pattern, but that is using paths currently. I have now edited my question and included almost all code. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the code that generates the axes appends `line` elements to the SVG. As it is run before appending the reference lines, calling `svg.selectAll("line").data(...)` matches the existing lines with the data. There are more lines than data elements, so no new elements need to be added and the `.enter()` selection is empty.

There are a few ways to fix this. You could move the code that generates the reference lines further up. You add a `g` element that contains these lines. You could have a special class for these lines and adjust the selector accordingly. Or you could provide a custom matching function to `.data()`.

Comment: Argh! I thought I had checked that there were no lines present, but it's quite obvious that the axes are using lines. Thanks! I'm not sure I understand this `.selectAll().enter().append()` pattern, where the selectAll()'s only aim normally is to match nothing! Changing `selectAll('line')` to `selectAll('.qwerty123')` made it work for example.